# How to implement Many to many relationship for USERS TABLE in ruby on rails without using any extra table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, many-to-many, associations

I am a newbie to the Ruby on Rails but stuck at this interesting situation :

I have three **Models** with me :

1. User
2. Company
3. Project

I want to relate them in the following way :

1. **Company** has_many **Users**
2. **Users** belong_to **Company**

   Implemented via **company_id** column in **USERS** table

   `User.Company` or `Company.Users` works fine.

---

1. **Project** has_and_belongs_to_many **Users**
2. **Users** has_and_belongs_to_many **Project**

   Implemented via **has_and_belongs_to_many** relation using in **projetcs_users** table

   `Project.Users` or `User.Projects` works fine.

---

The real problem comes when I want them to join as following as well :

1. **Company** belong_to **Owners**  (:through => User)
2. **Owner** has_one **Company**

   ---A **company** can have multiple **owners** but **one user** can own just **one company**. He can't be owner of multiple companies.

   ---A user may or may not be owner of a company but always belong to some company.
   ---A user cannot be part of two companies.
3. **Project** has_one **Project_manager**  (:through => User)
4. **Project_manager** belongs_to **Projects**

   ---A **Project** can have just one **Project_manager** but one can be project manager of multiple projects.

I am not able to figure out how the relationship should be defined in the **Models**. Also what should be the **table** structure for all three **models**.

My objective is to achieve :

1. Company.Owners

   It can be done by :

   `@owner = User.find(Company.owner_id)`
2. Project.Project_manager

   It can be done by :

   `@Project_manager = User.find(Project.project_manager_id)`

But don't want it that way to work !!

Rest is working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get on the right track:

```
class User
  # the owner relation
  #
  # user.owned_company 
  # => company
  #
  has_one :owned_company, :class_name => "Company", :foreign_key => "owner_id"

  # the project manager relation
  #
  # user.managed_projects 
  # => [project,...]
  #
  has_many :managed_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => "project_manager_id"
end

class Company
  # the owner relation
  #
  # company.owner
  # => user
  #
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
end

class Project
  # the project manager relation
  #
  # company.project_manager 
  # => user
  #
  belongs_to :project_manager, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Rails ActiveRecord relations are very well documented. See the documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks man finally able to figure out of my problem. Also able to understand the relation more clearly. Posting answer below for final output

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final output I am able to achieve :

---

### **-----Models-----**

**PROJECTS**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :project_manager, :class_name => "User"

end
```

**USERS**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :project_id

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :owned_company, :class_name => "Company", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  has_many :managed_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => "project_manager_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

end
```

**COMPANIES**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :users
  has_many :owners, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"  

end
```

### **-----Tables & Migrations-----**

**PROJECTS**

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :project_manager_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**USERS**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :project_id
      t.integer :owner_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**COMPANIES**

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Projects - Users - Join Table**

```
class CreateTableProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :projects_users,:id => false  do |t|
      t.integer :project_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
     drop_table :projects_users
  end
end
```